# how does shell recognize a SIGINT to one of its jobs

Tags: shell, signals

If we start a foreground process from shell, and using ctrl-c deliver it a SIGINT which it doesnt handles and hence exits, how does the shell know whether the process was killed by SIGINT. My assumption is that the process doesnt move into zombie by calling exit.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell uses functions from the `wait(2)` family to wait for the child to be killed / terminated , and to retrieve the signal that killed it if any.

Comment: but here the process hasnt exited calling exit(), so the wait method will not get any thing back.

Comment: Yes it will, read this : https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/wait.2.html

Answer (score 0):

An application which doesn't handle a signal, actually executes a default handler (which kills the app in the case of `SIGINT`). Delivering a signal to the application and calling the handler (whether default or set by application) is handled by the operating system, so there is a place where the OS can take notice which signal killed the application and e.g. to set the exit code accordingly. The shell only displays the exit code, but it's the OS which sets it.